# Prevent Site Collection Administrator from viewing library documents

Tags: document-library, permissions, site-collection, administration

Is there any way to prevent a site collection administrator from accessing a document library? (Or at least from seeing the documents within it?)

I have created a document library with read/write access for managers, however, since I have Site Collection Admin permissions I can still access the Doc Library and read/ write to it.

Is there any way to revoke my permissions to this library WITHOUT removing me as a Site Collection Administrator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Their is no way to block site collection administrators from viewing anything on that site collection.

You have to think different strategy i.e.

- enabling auditing so that who ever access that library, his presence recorded
- use password protected files, which shared only with user who should have access
- or change site collection admin permission to full control then break inheritance on the library.

Comment: Another way of looking at it to supplement your answer is that a Site Collection Administrator *bypasses* all security permissions.  There is nothing anyone with full control can do to stop a SCA.